Definition of semimartingale in discrete-time
I'm looking for references on the definition of semimartingales in discrete-time. Based on my understanding, is the following definition correct?

A discrete-time process $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is called a semimartingale if it can be decomposed as:
$X_n = M_n + A_n - B_n$
where:

$(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale
$(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are two predictable increasing processes


